# Data Source Connection Changes

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data source called gcss which connects to 10.221.87.48(redshift)
This is a Tableau Data extract on the server.

I have 8 workbooks that connect to this data source.
Now I want to change the data source ip address to 10.221.87.52(Production)

Is there an easier way to do this ?
Presently Im creating new data source in tableau workbook in tableau desktop and then replacing the old connection with the new one. However some metadata changes are disturbing my workbook.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the ellipse button next to the data source name. A menu will show up and one option is to Edit Connection. Choose that option and you'll see a connection dialog box. Change the connection information there.

Tableau's online help has this detailed at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/connections_modify.htm.